# Trying to put several textviews in a Button

Tags: android, button, textview, imagebutton

I think I might be doing something stupid but I cannot find the answer. Obviously ht ebelow thing doesn't work but how would I do it?

```
<Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+@id/date"
                android:text="+@id/heading"
                android:text="+@id/subheading"

                android:drawableLeft="+@id/featuredimage"
            />
```

I'm basically making an articlebutton to represent an article for a blog. I tried putting textviews inside but it miscounted the ending tags and threw an error.

What is that best way to create one of these buttons?

Comment: why not use a textview and append your data to the textview?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dont use Button.

Use a Linear/Relative layout, with the attribute:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Inside this layout add all your TextViews or any other thing you want.